# I new in ruby on rails and i don't know how select_tag works

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my select_tag:

```
<div class="card-body">
          <%= form_tag services_path, :method=> "get", :id => "filter_form" do %>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= select_tag :filter, options_for_select([[t('italy'), "it"], [t('world_wide'), "en"]], selected: params[:filter] ? params[:filter] : I18n.locale),  class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= submit_tag t('research'), name: nil, class: "btn btn-default bg-primary text-light" %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
```

and these are the buttons:

```
<%= link_to(t('impact_hub'),
                               external_service_goto_path("impacthub-coworking"),
                               class: "btn btn-light-primary font-weight-bold m-1",
                                target: "_blank") %>

                      

                      
                  <%= link_to(t('my_spot'),
                               external_service_goto_path("myspot-coworking"),
                               class: "btn btn-light-primary font-weight-bold m-1",
                                target: "_blank") %>
```

I don't know how to show buttons when I select "italy" in select and not show them when I select world_wide

Comment: You will likely use javascript for something like showing/hiding on button click.  Are you familiar with javascript or using jQuery?

Comment: In this case how could i do with javascript?

Comment: Check the examples here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event
Similarly you can have an on change event for your select, and then have an IF statement that checks if the currently selected value is "italy", then show the buttons, and if not, hide the buttons.